# Выключаются мониторы и шумит видеокарта

Tags: железо, пк, совместимость

Играл в гта 5 онлайн и резко погас монитор и видеокарта загудела.В самой игре температура карты была в среднем 62 градуса.Решил проверить в стресс тесте и там произошло тоже самое спустя 15 минут при температуре 74 градуса.А в третий раз в стресс тесте прошло довольно таки много времени и всё работало.Получается такая ситуация что это происходит рандомно.Что это может быть помогите пожалуйста!

Если что вот комплектующие:

Блок: Cugar 500w

Проц: i7 4770

Материнка: gigabyte h81m-s2pv

Видюха: 1660ti

Comment: `резко погас монитор и видеокарта загудела` очень похоже на провал в питании... если так - либо напруга в сети просела, либо бп перестал тянуть(возможно железку какую докинул, или софт какой обновился до более прожорливой версии). вообще **`**60ti`** держать на 500w... ну так себе затея. + стоит проверить силовую проводку на наличие повреждений.

Comment: Спасибо за совет